# Understanding NSS PK11_CipherOp and C memory allocation

Tags: c, encryption, memory-management, nss

Having some issues with C. I have this is my code:

```
// First line works, second line does not! 
char outbuf[1024];
// char *outbuf = (char *) malloc(1024);  // char is always 1
```

I am passing this outbuf to a method called `PK11_CipherOp()`, declared in the NSS library. The Documentation for this method can be found [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/pk11cxt.c#666), you can see that it expects a `char *` for the outbuf param.

I cannot understand why the first line works reliably, and the second line does not!

To see the full code, please see [File Source](http://code.google.com/p/sysecure/source/browse/trunk/session_keys.c?spec=svn25&r=25#118)

Thanks,

Hamilton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem appears to be a missing declaration for `malloc` - you haven't included `<stdlib.h>`.

This means that your compiler is assuming the function returns `int`, which is then being explicitly cast to `(unsigned char *)`.  If you are on a platform where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void *)`, like x86-64, then this will mangle the pointer value.

This illustrates perfectly why in C (unlike C++) you should **not** cast the result of `malloc()` - doing so is unnecessary, and hides this exact bug from you.  It also illustrates why you should turn on compiler warnings.

The fix is to `#include <stdlib.h>`, and remove the cast from `malloc()` while you're there.

**Addendum:**

Your other issue is that you're passing `sizeof(outbuf)` to `PK11_CipherOp()`.  This will be correct (equal to `out_buf_size`) when `outbuf` is an array, but is incorrect (the size of the *pointer itself*) when `outbuf` is a pointer.

Replace each `sizeof(outbuf)` with `out_buf_size` and you should be good to go (there's another one later too)...

Comment: caf, 

Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, that did not fix the issue. I have warnings on (and didnt get one about declaring malloc), but I implemented your solution just to be sure. 

You can see the updated source at http://code.google.com/p/sysecure/source/browse/trunk/session_keys.c?r=27#119

When run, this prints: 
sysecure: Error when attempting to encrypt message
sysecure: Failure to perform cipher operation (err -8189)
sysecure: Error Name - ((null))
sysecure: Error Message - (Unknown code ___f 3)

and to stderr
Encrypted Data: 
Data length 0 


Any thoughts would really help me out.

Comment: Ah yes, there's a second issue there too - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Turns out that I was using `sizeof(outbuf)` as one of the parameters. When the outbuf is declared on the stack, as `char outbuf[1024];` this returns 1024. However, when outbuf is on the heap, as `char * outbuf = malloc(1024);` the size of outbuf is just 4. This parameter told the function how much room was available in the outbuf, so the function thought that it only had 4 bytes of room. It needs 16 to do *anything* so it just returned without performing any work.